# Tpot isnan error

Tags: python, tpot

I posted previously with a similar problem ([Categorical Data with tpot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49822035/categorical-data-with-tpot)). Thanks to Randy, I was able to get the code running, but now that I am stopping it hours later, I am getting a similar error:

```
  File "XXXXXXXX", line 832, in score
    if np.any(np.isnan(testing_features)):

TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

I'm not sure if I'm stopping it incorrectly (I just hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> in spyder) or there is some other issue. I made sure the data is all numerical including feature titles. Any idea what may be the problem?

Here is the code I'm running:

```
train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y=train_test_split(x,y)
train_x=pd.get_dummies(train_x).values
from tpot import TPOTRegressor

regressor=TPOTRegressor()
regressor.fit(train_x,train_y)
print(regressor.score(test_x,test_y))
```

I don't know how to show the contents of train and test arrays.
train_x is a size (2400,62) float64 and train_y is a (2400,) size series.

Comment: what the type of `testing_features` ?

Comment: How can I find the type of the variable? It's within the tpot code. I'm sorry I'm new to python.

Comment: Then, can you show the code you use to call the function that cause an error?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I completely forgot that part. I'll edit the post above to include my code.

Comment: Which line cause the error? (EDIT: I just saw it's the score call). Try `print(type(test_x), type(test_y))`.

Comment: The error is from the line: print(regressor.score(test_x,test_y)). Do you know if ctrl c is the correct way to stop the code early?

Comment: ctrl+c should stop the code execution. Try to reset your workspace if you have one.

Comment: test_x is a dataframe. and test_y is a series. That might be my problem. I just changed test_x to float64 with the one hot encoder. I'll try to run it again.

Comment: Just to clarify, I should reset my workspace to stop the tpot optimization and read current results? I can reset my variables, but wouldn't that not stop the code execution?

Comment: @DeborahPaul, make sure you're running the testing features through the same preprocessing steps as the training features. Those preprocessing steps are at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49823248/1383444

Answer (score 1):

Using the first solution gave me the following error,

```
x_train = x_train.astype(np.float64)
x_test = x_test.astype(np.float64)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Converting the features to numpy array does the trick for me. Even though they were initially numpy arrays

```
x_train = np.array(list(x_train), dtype=np.float)
x_test = np.array(list(x_test), dtype=np.float)
```

[python](/questions/tagged/python) [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason TPOT returns this error related to `isnan` when the error is the type. Ensure your features are converted to floats:

```
X = X.astype(np.float64)
```